# How to Expose Boost::shared_ptr<T> to Tcl + SWIG interface file?

Tags: c++, tcl, swig

I want to expose the `boost::shared_Ptr` to Tcl layer using SWIG. but currently I don't know I could Expose this. I found out that SWIG/Lib folder contains the interface file for `shared_ptr.i`. But in the content I found out that I could not use it directly. It has to be included after "`boost_shared_ptr.i`". But there is nothing like `boost_shared_ptr.i` in "`SWIG/Lib/tcl`" folder but we have similar interface which I could include in Java.

Comment: Wish I could help, but I've never done C++/Tcl binding in a substantive way, and certainly haven't done it with SWIG. (I know a bit about how to bind fundamental types, but `shared_ptr`? No idea at all. I work much more with plain old C…)

Comment: You are not trying to expose T as a parameter to Tcl, are you ?

Comment: I actually want to create handles for boost::shared_ptr<T> in tcl.

Answer (score 3):

When I last tried there was not good support for boost/shared_ptr in all of SWIG.  Python had the best coverage.  I am interested to hear if this has changed.

As far as my other experience with SWIG you would also need to instantiate the template using %template for each type that you want to expose.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use standard shared_ptr? I mean std::tr1::shared_ptr? In gcc you would need to

```
#include <tr1/memory>
```

Comment: I cannot use std::tr1::shared_ptr, as my library is going to be used for both Java and TCL and I have already exposed everything on Java and it seems to be working fine there.

Comment: What is more Microsoft failed with C++0x compatibility. It works on WIN XP SP2 or latter, so if you make project, which going to have many users, you cannot use it yet.